# Czech and Slovak Keyboard layout not correct in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: keyboard, layout

If I press Caps Lock, there it should be possible to get Upper case letter like ČŘŽŠ.
This works at Ubuntu 23.04, but if i do so in Ubuntu 23.10., only lower case letters appear : čřžš
Is this a known bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, albeit an inconvenient one :
Choose "Keyboard Czech UCW" and then press Caps Lock + the wanted diacritic letter :

Press S -> Š occurs
C -> Č
R -> Ř
T -> Ť
D -> Ď

Attention: Press Y to get Ž !